# Calling a method within another method

Tags: c#, .net

When a product is sold my intended behaviour is for productSold in ProductManagement to call `inventory.UpdateProduct()` and dynamically update inventory.

I've applied some breakpoints and found when p.productSold(p1) is called, it never actually enters `inventory.UpdateProduct()` and so inventory is never updated.

To play around with this I've explicitly called the method in main `inv.UpdateProduct(item id, quantity)` and it seems to be working however, I would like UpdateProduct to be called when productSold is.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Products        
        Product p1 = new Product(1, 20, 1000);

        // Inventory 
        Inventory inv = new Inventory();
        ProductManagement p = new ProductManagement();

        // Add Products to inventory
        inv.AddProduct(p1);

        // Products sold
        p.productSold(p1);

        //inv.UpdateProduct(1,50);

        // View Inventory
        inv.ViewInventory();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

```
class Product
{
    public int _id;
    public int _price;
    public int _quantity;

    public Product(int id, int price, int quantity)
    {
        _id = id;
        _price = price;
        _quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Inventory
{
    private List<Product> inventory = new List<Product>();

    public Inventory()
    {

    }

    public void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        inventory.Add(product);
    }

    public void UpdateProduct(int id, int quantity)
    {
        foreach(Product p in inventory)
        {
            if (p._id == id)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("product found");
                p._quantity -= quantity;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("cannot find product");
            }
        }
        /* var product = inventory.Single(x => x._id == id);
                      product._quantity -= quantity; */
    }

    public void ViewInventory()
    {
        foreach(Product p in inventory)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item ID : {0} Item Price : {1} Item Quantity : {2}", p._id, p._quantity, p._quantity);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
 class ProductManagement
{
    public Inventory inventory = new Inventory();

    public void productSold(Product product)
    {
        var quantitySold = 1;
        inventory.UpdateProduct(product._id, quantitySold);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Inventory" inside your "ProductManagement" isn't the same inventory you have in your Main function.

You can make the following changes to your ProductManagement:
(Add a constructor with parameter)

```
public class ProductManagement
{
    public Inventory inventory;

    public ProductManagement(Inventory inv)
    {
        this.inventory = inv;
    }

    public void productSold(Product product)
    {
        var quantitySold = 1;
        inventory.UpdateProduct(product._id, quantitySold);
    }
}
```

Change your Main as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{     
    Product p1 = new Product(1, 20, 1000);

    Inventory inv = new Inventory();
    ProductManagement p = new ProductManagement(inv); //THE CHANGE

    inv.AddProduct(p1);

    p.productSold(p1);

    inv.ViewInventory();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```